# SQLite query returning "syntax error Unable to execute statement"

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I just updated one of my databases including the creation of a new table, AUTO_VERIFICATION. That table is created with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTO_VERIFICATION (stock text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, current_value double, last_high double, last_low double)
```

Later when trying to insert the first entry using the same kind of code I already used successfully to insert data in other tables, I get an error in the following way (this uses my app's custom error message):

```
Error in call to MShareDatabase::execQuery: near \"0.00\": syntax error Unable to execute statement (query: INSERT INTO AUTO_VERIFICATION (stock, current_value, last_high, last_low) VALUES ('CYRE3', 0.00, 0.00, 0.00)
```

I just can't understand this error! I already checked with other parts of the code where I create other tables and insert data into them and it's the same syntax. I also used one of these websites where you can check if your SQL syntax is fine and it returned OK to me.

Could anybody please tell me what is the problem?

I'm using SQLite with Qt 5.5 and just for the record all other database transaction functions in my code (quite a lot) are working fine.

Comment: Works fine here with sqlite 3.10.2 on the command line. I'm not sure if the locale might affect you and dot is not interpreted as decimal seperator?

Comment: @Olli well that's pretty much what I expect to here from everybody xD Seriously, this error is crazy! Either way I don't think that's the case: as I stated, the query has the same syntax of every other query and the others works fine. Still I'll try to check if I may be missing something regarding that. Thanks!

Comment: Very crazy error! How do you create the query? Have you tried with values binding? (QSqlQuery::bindValue)

Comment: do You use QSqlQuery value binding? what QT version? what sqLite3 version? Maybe You're using sqlite2 not sqlite3?

Answer (score 2):

I got it: a closing parenthesis ")" is missing at the end of the query (the one that is being shown is actually part of the error message, not the query itself).

Thanks for all the help,

Momergil